Electron Forge with TS and Webpack - navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia error with admin permission
I'm using Electron forge with TS and Webpack. Problematic part is navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia. Everything is ok when app is running as usual, but I need to run as administrator. Running as administrator ends with error:

DOMException: Could not start video source

Code:
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
const stream = await (navigator.mediaDevices as any).getUserMedia({
  audio: false,
  video: {
    mandatory: {
      chromeMediaSource: "desktop",
      chromeMediaSourceId: sourceId,
    },
  },
});

Same code written in vanilla JS works great when running in both, usual way and as administrator. I'm thinking it's TS and Webpack but I'm wandering.
Any ideas what am I missing or doing wrong?
